# limit choices of manytomanyfield to a foreginkey

Tags: django, foreign-keys, manytomanyfield

let's say i have these classes :

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Family(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    child = models.ManyToManyField(Child)
```

the problem with this code the family form shows all the "Child" objects.

I need to show "Child" objects only if the Child is related to "Parent" objects in the family form.

if there's a way not to use manytomanyfield i am open to that too..

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution can help!

```
class Parent(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Family(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

    filtered_childs = Child.objects.all().filter(parent=self.parent)
    filtered_childs = list((k, v) for k, v in enumerate(filtered_childs))
    child = models.CharField(choices=filtered_childs, max_length=20)
```

Comment: didn't work. am I suppose to add something to the code?